# Writing events to Windows Event Log using Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, event-log, coldfusion-10

Is there a way (built-in or underlying java library installed with ColdFusion) that would enable a ColdFusion 10 application to write messages to the Windows Event Log?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Log4J to accomplish this. There is also a DLL that's required to be placed on the PATH of the Windows file system (depending on your environment). See the [NTEventLogAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/nt/NTEventLogAppender.html) class for details:

Log4J will be packaged with your build since Hibernate uses it. However, you will likely need to do some extra configuring per the DLL I mentioned above (also noted in the referenced javadocs).

You can also check out [Log4jna](https://github.com/dblock/log4jna%20log4jna), which has native appenders unlike Log4J. Using this library will not require you to mess with the DLL dependency for Log4J. **This does not come with CF10 though.** It's out of scope of your question, but still may be an option to consider.

An example of code you can potentially use if you stick with Log4J (reference to the [PatternLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html)):

```
oLogger = createObject("java", "org.apache.log4j.Logger");
oNTAppender = createObject("java", "org.apache.log4j.nt.NTEventLogAppender");
oLayout = createObject("java", "PatternLayout").init("[%c][%l][%p][%thread]: %m%n");

// create the appender with your source and layout
oNTAppender = oNTAppender.init("[your source text]", oLayout);

// add this appender to the logger
oLogger.addAppender(oNTAppender);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to checkout Log4jna to try to keep things simple.